# Connect ODBC Driver that is in remote machine

Tags: odbc, linked-server, jdbc-odbc

Usually, we connect `ODBC` driver using BI applications on our local machine,
Just imagine I created an `ODBC` driver for `PostgreSQL` in the remote machine at my home (Windows 10), I want to connect that `ODBC` driver (remotely) from my office workstation (windows 8) using any BI application (such as Excel, power Bi). For this, I have to find the solution to update the driver for the remote concept. so that please refer any technology that does this.

> Note: the PostgreSQL can be on any machine like the same windows 10 machine or any other server machine.

[Reference](http://cdn.cdata.com/help/DGC/odbc/pg_remotingintroo.htm)